# Difficult integration

Tags: integration, fourier-series

In my notes the lecturer takes the Fourier transform in $x, y$ and $t$ of $\phi(x,y,z,t)$ as:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt\, e^{i\omega t}\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}\,dx\,dy\,e^{-i(k_1x+k_2y)}\nabla^2\phi(x,y,z,t)=\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}-k^2\right)\widetilde{\phi}(k_1,k_2,z,\omega)
$$
but how does he compute the integral? I would've guessed integration by parts but how do you integrate, for instance, the $\partial_{xx}e^{-i(k_1x+k_2y)}$ term?

On a related note, how do you take the gradient of a function that depends on $x, y, z, t$. Do we just get $\nabla=(\partial_x, \partial_y, \partial_z,\partial_t)$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, integration by parts is a straightforward way to go about it (assuming the function is integrable, the boundary terms vanish, etc. which is often the case in these sorts of problems). I would suggest starting with the simple case
$$\int \mathrm{d}x\,e^{-ikx}\partial_x f(x)$$
to see how it works. You will get a factor of $\partial_x e^{-ikx}$, which you can evaluate directly - it's just a derivative - and the resulting integral can be expressed in terms of $\tilde f(k)$.

This shows you the general principle that a Fourier transform turns differential operators into factors of $-ik$. Once you've verified $\partial_x \to -ik$ from the simple example, you can hopefully figure out the derivation for $\partial_{xx}\to -k^2$. Also, it shouldn't be too hard to generalize this to multiple dimensions. Remember that
$$\nabla^2 = \partial_{xx} + \partial_{yy} + \partial_{zz}$$

Comment: I'll be honest - I just realised you could change the order of integration, which makes the integration by parts easy. If the generalisation of the gradient is $\nabla = (\partial_x, \partial_y, \partial_z, \partial_t)$ then do you not end up with a $-\omega^2$ term? Do you not need it to be  $(\partial_x, \partial_y, \partial_z, \frac{1}{c} \partial_t)$ instead, where we have $\omega = ck$ for some $c$

Comment: Well, what makes you so convinced that $\nabla$ represents the generalization of the gradient rather than the gradient itself, $(\partial_x, \partial_y, \partial_z)$? Note that if you were working with the operator $(\partial_x, \partial_y, \partial_z, \frac{1}{c}\partial_t)$, you would probably also be working in Minkowski space, where the scalar product is $a\cdot b = \pm(a_x b_x + a_y b_y + a_z b_z - a_t b_t)$ (the $\pm$ is a choice of convention).